# sending data from max30100 sensor using esp8266 to thingspeak

Tags: sensors, esp8266, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

I have two sensors linked to my `Arduino UNO`: `MAX30100(this is the problem) and LM35 Sensor`.
These two sensors work without the ESP8266, their values are shown on the Serial port of arduino.
`The problem is when I include the ESP8266 to send the values to ThingSpeak`. The values for LM35 sensor are sent and they appear well on ThingSpeak.
`The problem is with MAX30100. MAX30100 show just the value 0, that means that MAX30100 is not measuring nothing at all.`
Does anybody has any ideea what to do to make the MAX30100 sensor to work while sending data to Thingspeak? I post my code below.

```
#define USE_ARDUINO_INTERRUPTS true    
#define DEBUG true
#define SSID "Redmi"     // "SSID-WiFiname"
#define PASS "wtfwtfwtf" // "password"
#define IP "184.106.153.149"      // thingspeak.com ip
#define RX 10
#define TX 11
#include <Wire.h>
#include "Stdlib.h"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "Timer.h"
#include <PulseSensorPlayground.h> // Includes the PulseSensorPlayground 
Library.   
Timer t;
#include "MAX30100_PulseOximeter.h"
#define REPORTING_PERIOD_MS     1000
PulseOximeter pox;
uint32_t tsLastReport = 0;
String msg = "GET /update?key=T4RF5YWLJKOU9MVO"; 
SoftwareSerial esp8266(RX,TX);

//Variables
const int PulseWire = A0;       // PulseSensor PURPLE WIRE connected to ANALOG PIN 0
const int LED13 = 13;          // The on-board Arduino LED, close to PIN 13.
int Threshold = 550;           //for heart rate sensor
float myTemp;
int myBPM;
float  mybpm;
float  mySPO2;
String BPM;
String temp;
String SPO2;
int error;
int panic;

int raw_myTemp;
float Voltage;
float tempC;
void onBeatDetected()
{
    Serial.println("Beat!");
}
void setup()
{

   Serial.begin(9600); 
   esp8266.begin(115200);


   if (!pox.begin()) {
    Serial.println("FAILED");
    for(;;);
    } 
else {
    Serial.println("SUCCESS");
}


// Double-check the "pulseSensor" object was created and "began" seeing a signal. 
//This prints one time at Arduino power-up,  or on Arduino reset.  

pox.setIRLedCurrent(MAX30100_LED_CURR_7_6MA);

// Register a callback for the beat detection
pox.setOnBeatDetectedCallback(onBeatDetected);
Serial.println("AT");
esp8266.println("AT");

delay(3000);

if(esp8266.find("OK"))
{
connectWiFi();
}

}

void loop()
{
 panic_button();
 start: //label
 error=0;
 t.update();
//Resend if transmission is not completed
if (error==1)
{
  goto start; //go to label "start"
} 
delay(1000);
panic_button();

delay(1000);
panic_button();
onBeatDetected();
delay(1000);
panic_button();
heart();
delay(1000);
panic_button();
oxygen();
delay(1000);
 panic_button();
temp1();

}

boolean connectWiFi()
{
Serial.println("AT+CWMODE=1");
esp8266.println("AT+CWMODE=1");
delay(2000);
String cmd="AT+CWJAP=\"";
cmd+=SSID;
cmd+="\",\"";
cmd+=PASS;
cmd+="\"";
Serial.println(cmd);
esp8266.println(cmd);
delay(5000);
if(esp8266.find("OK"))
{
  return true;
}
else
{
  return false;
}
}


void temp1(){
raw_myTemp = analogRead(A1);
Voltage = (raw_myTemp / 1023.0) * 5000; // 5000 to get millivots.
myTemp = Voltage * 0.1; 
Serial.print("Temperature = ");
Serial.print(myTemp);
Serial.print(" Degree Celsius\n");
delay(20);
char buffer3[10];
temp = dtostrf(myTemp, 4, 1, buffer3);
String cmd = "AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"";
cmd += IP;
cmd += "\",80";
Serial.println(cmd);
esp8266.println(cmd);
delay(10000);
if(esp8266.find("Error"))
{
  return;
}
cmd = msg ;
cmd += "&field3=";    //field 1 for BPM
cmd += temp;
cmd += "\r\n";
Serial.print("AT+CIPSEND=");
esp8266.print("AT+CIPSEND=");
Serial.println(cmd.length());
esp8266.println(cmd.length());
if(esp8266.find(">"))
{
  Serial.print(cmd);
  esp8266.print(cmd);
}
else
{
  Serial.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
  esp8266.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
  //Resend...
  error=1;
}
}

void heart(){

pox.update();
if (millis() - tsLastReport > REPORTING_PERIOD_MS) {
    Serial.print("Heart rate:");
   
    Serial.print(pox.getHeartRate());
       Serial.println(""); 
       tsLastReport = millis();}
     float mybpm = pox.getHeartRate();
     delay(20);            
char buffer1[10];

BPM = dtostrf(mybpm, 4, 1, buffer1);
 String cmd = "AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"";
cmd += IP;
cmd += "\",80";
Serial.println(cmd);
esp8266.println(cmd);
delay(1000);
if(esp8266.find("Error"))
{
  return;
}
cmd = msg ;
cmd += "&field1=";    //field 1 for BPM
cmd += mybpm;
cmd += "\r\n";
Serial.print("AT+CIPSEND=");
esp8266.print("AT+CIPSEND=");
Serial.println(cmd.length());
esp8266.println(cmd.length());
if(esp8266.find(">"))
{
  Serial.print(cmd);
  esp8266.print(cmd);
}
else
{
Serial.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
esp8266.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
//Resend...
error=1;
}
}
void oxygen(){
pox.update();
if (millis() - tsLastReport > REPORTING_PERIOD_MS) {
    
    Serial.print("bpm / SPO2::");
    
    Serial.print(pox.getSpO2());
    Serial.println("%"); 
       tsLastReport = millis();}
     /*int mySPO2 = pox.getSpO2();*/
     delay(20);            
char buffer2[10];

SPO2 = dtostrf(pox.getSpO2(), 4, 1, buffer2);
 String cmd = "AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"";
cmd += IP;
cmd += "\",80";
Serial.println(cmd);
esp8266.println(cmd);
delay(2000);
if(esp8266.find("Error"))
{
return;
}
cmd = msg ;
cmd += "&field2=";    //field 1 for BPM
cmd +=SPO2;
cmd += "\r\n";
Serial.print("AT+CIPSEND=");
esp8266.print("AT+CIPSEND=");
Serial.println(cmd.length());
esp8266.println(cmd.length());
if(esp8266.find(">"))
{
Serial.print(cmd);
esp8266.print(cmd);
}
else
{
Serial.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
esp8266.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
//Resend...
error=1;
}

}

void panic_button(){
panic = digitalRead(8);
if(panic == HIGH){

Serial.println(panic);
  String cmd = "AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"";
cmd += IP;
cmd += "\",80";
Serial.println(cmd);
esp8266.println(cmd);
delay(2000);
if(esp8266.find("Error"))
{
return;
}
cmd = msg ;
cmd += "&field4=";    
cmd += panic;
cmd += "\r\n";
Serial.print("AT+CIPSEND=");
esp8266.print("AT+CIPSEND=");
Serial.println(cmd.length());
esp8266.println(cmd.length());
if(esp8266.find(">"))
{
  Serial.print(cmd);
  esp8266.print(cmd);
}
else
{
  Serial.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
  esp8266.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
  //Resend...
  error=1;
} 
}
}
```

Expected Output: The values of MAX30100 and LM35 should be displayed on Serial monitor and uploaded to ThingSpeak platform.

Comment: MAX30100 requires a non-blocking loop, while your code with all the `delay(1000)` and AT commands are blocking in nature. Also clean up your code, it is difficult to read. You don't need to send data over http for every sensor reading, you could do it by send all 3 readings in one connection.